# VSCode extension render \n decoration

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am building an extension to render parts certain single-line expressions on multiple lines, without inserting an actual newline character in the document (equivalent to wrapping).

I want `test:world` to turn into

```js
test:
world
```

I use the following decorator

```js
    const regex = /test:/g

// ... and then later 
            const decorator = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({
                after: {
                    contentText: '\n',
                }
            })
```

but see no effect. Yet if I do

```js
                after: {
                    contentText: 'FOO\n',
                }
```

I successfully see the editor render

```js
test:FOOworld
```

Does the VSCode decorator API not allow for rendering non-existent newlines? How do they achieve the wrapping effect if not?